# JavaScript (w/jQuery) - grow an element to fill container on hover, when surrounded by other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid of elements (3 x 3) formation which toggle visibility on hover, easy.

However my next step is to grow said elements to fill their container when hovered upon, I'm assuming I would need to get current (x,y) values and then grow this to the (x,y) values of the parent container and use css positioning, however every approach I take is hitting a brick wall. I have a fiddle here which demonstrates the layout / intended functionality - http://jsfiddle.net/u2w7J/

Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The way your HTML is set up currently, this is kind of hard to accomplish while having it look smooth. A first try is to use the .toggleClass function and toggle "box" and "miniBox" for the hovered element. See http://jsfiddle.net/u2w7J/6/ for a demo.

Positioning is harder since the miniBoxes are not positioned absolutely. Hence, adding animation is causing weird results (see above demo).

I would suggest to have the miniBoxes positioned absolutely. When hovering, get the parents div left and top values and animate the miniBox using these values. Additionally, raise z-index during or before the animation to prevent other miniBoxes being visible.

Comment: Thanks for this, I might refactor the html and place absolutely as per your suggestion, I was also considering cloning the current element then making it move to and grow from centre as a perhaps "easier" option.